# Why Gluon Mobile app for android platform fail to compile on wsl Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: maven-2, java-11, gluon-mobile

I am trying to develop android apk file by using wsl Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with maven plugins. I followed all requirements from https://docs.gluonhq.com/ and I have managed to perform some tasks correctly. The problem arise when running command
mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build , compiling task failed and throws outputs as:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------< com.gluonmaven.linux:gluonmavenlinux >----------------
[INFO] Building GluonMavenLinux 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.16:build (default-cli) @ gluonmavenlinux ---
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------< com.gluonmaven.linux:gluonmavenlinux >----------------
[INFO] Building GluonMavenLinux 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.16:compile (default-cli) > process-classes @ gluonmavenlinux >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ gluonmavenlinux ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ gluonmavenlinux ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to /mnt/d/Epicstats/GluonMavenLinux/target/classes
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.16:compile (default-cli) < process-classes @ gluonmavenlinux <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.16:compile (default-cli) @ gluonmavenlinux ---
[Tue Dec 06 15:05:28 EAT 2022][INFO] ==================== COMPILE TASK ====================
             _______  ___      __   __  _______  __    _
            |       ||   |    |  | |  ||       ||  |  | |
            |    ___||   |    |  | |  ||   _   ||   |_| |
            |   | __ |   |    |  |_|  ||  | |  ||       |
            |   ||  ||   |___ |       ||  |_|  ||  _    |
            |   |_| ||       ||       ||       || | |   |
            |_______||_______||_______||_______||_|  |__|

    Access to the latest docs, tips and tricks and more info on
[Tue Dec 06 15:05:30 EAT 2022][INFO] We will now compile your code for aarch64-linux-android. This may take some time.
    how to get support? Register your usage of Gluon Substrate now at

    https://gluonhq.com/activate



[Tue Dec 06 15:05:30 EAT 2022][SEVERE] Process compile-additional-sources failed with result: 2
Check the log files under /mnt/d/Epicstats/GluonMavenLinux/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.
[Tue Dec 06 15:05:30 EAT 2022][INFO] Logging process [compile-additional-sources] to file: /mnt/d/Epicstats/GluonMavenLinux/target/gluonfx/log/process-compile-additional-sources-1670328330610.log
[Tue Dec 06 15:05:30 EAT 2022][SEVERE] Compiling failed.
Check the log files under /mnt/d/Epicstats/GluonMavenLinux/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.542 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-06T15:05:30+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.16:compile (default-cli) on project gluonmavenlinux: Compiling failed -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.094 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-06T15:05:30+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.16:build (default-cli) on project gluonmavenlinux: Error, gluonfx:build failed -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.16:build (default-cli) on project gluonmavenlinux: Error, gluonfx:build failed
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error, gluonfx:build failed
    at com.gluonhq.NativeBuildMojo.execute (NativeBuildMojo.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have tried to resolve the problem by not running mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build
and running mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:compile but the problem still exit. Later on I discovered that gluonfx:build is a combination of gluonfx:compile and gluonfx:link

Where might I be making mistakes, anyone who has an Idea.

I am using:
JDK 11
apache-maven-3.8.1
android-ndk-r25b
graalvm-svm-java11-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final

Comment: @José Pereda can you help me out of this problem.

Comment: You haven't posted any stack trace so impossible to say... But: check the logs (as the message already says!) under `/mnt/d/Epicstats/GluonMavenLinux/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/log` or `/mnt/d/Epicstats/GluonMavenLinux/target/gluonfx/log`. Post whatever you find significant. Also, does it work for Linux (`mvn gluonfx:build`)?

Comment: @José Pereda
I just run ( mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build ) and it produces the output above.

Comment: Yes, so see my comment above??

Comment: @José Pereda I have edited my outputs and include stacktraces.

Comment: Start with something more simple: `mvn gluonfx:run`. That should run your project on Linux with JVM (and not with GraalVM native image). If that doesn't work, your settings are not correct.

Comment: @ José Pereda when run with (mvn gluonfx:run) on terminal it fails, but when run on Intellij idea it works fine.

Comment: `mvn gluonfx:run` _should_ work in any case from terminal (under the root of the project, that is). Does  even `mvn compile` work?

Comment: @José Pereda
Yes, ( mvn compiler:compile ) work fine.

Comment: `mvn javafx:run`, `mvn gluonfx:run` should work as well. Else post errors?